# how to check if output folder is created in java?

Tags: java

I am coming to an issue where I am trying to check if output folder is there and if not create one in my code below. So, I tried doing that way as shown in my code but I dont know if its the proper a way of doing it? can you please advise. thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
String outputFolder2 = Printer.getOutputFolder();
File outFileTwo = new File(outputFolder2);
if (!outFileTwo.exists()) {
 if (!outFileTwo.mkdir()) {
 System.out.println("Failed to make directory for: " + outputFolder2);
 }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at java.nio.Files.createFile  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)

Answer (score 1):

To check if the directory exists:

```
 Files.isDirectory(Paths.get("/the/path"))
```

To create dir if not exists:

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/the/path"))
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. however, can I do this in my code like `File outFileTwo = Files.createDirectories(PayStubPrinter.getOutputFolder(/)`, right?

Comment: if u need it as a file u can use path.toFile() afterwards

Comment: I just need to check if a output folder is there if not create a output folder

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
dirPathFileObj.mkdir();
```

From *java.io.File;*

If the method detects that no such directory exists, it will automatically create one. Otherwise, it will simply do nothing in terms of File creation.

Comment: Also note, if you have previous directories to traverse to where you will create the output folder, either state it in the path carefully or call ```dirObj.mkdirs()```. Note the *s* at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use the nio package for new code that interacts with files -- it's faster, and easier to code for.  Here's how I would write that code, in the form of a junit test that I ran to verify it:

```
  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    Path dirPath = Paths.get("C:/I/do/not/exist");
    Path filePath = dirPath.resolve("newFile.txt");
    try {
        assertFalse(Files.exists(dirPath));
        dirPath = createDirectories(dirPath);
        filePath = Files.createFile(filePath);
        assertTrue(Files.exists(filePath));

    } catch (IOException iox) {
        iox.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            Files.deleteIfExists(filePath);
            Files.deleteIfExists(dirPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This will create `C:\I\do\not\exist\newFile.txt`, then delete `C:\I\do\not\exist`, (leaving `C:\I\do\not\`).  For production code, you'd want to remove the asserts and fill in those `catch` clauses

Comment: thanks for your answer.. will test this soon